# How to add custom slider for textfield

Tags: javascript

I read:

- [Best way for including javascript/jQuery OnLoad in EVERY page on my site](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/3409/best-way-for-including-javascript-jquery-onload-in-every-page-on-my-site)
- [How to get jquery working on Drupal 7 - for Newbies](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/71787/how-to-get-jquery-working-on-drupal-7-for-newbies)
- [How to include jQuery UI on a page without PHP?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/19688/how-to-include-jquery-ui-on-a-page-without-php)

I'm using [jQuery Update](https://drupal.org/project/jquery_update) module. Tried different versions of jQuery.

I have theme tao_test (that is subtheme of Tao). In tao_test.info I added:

```
scripts[] = scripts/ranger.js
```

And inside of this js file is this code:

```
(function($){

    Drupal.behaviors.tao_test = {
      attach: function(context, settings) {

          $("input#edit-field-range-test").before("<div class='range-slider'></div>");

          $(".range-slider").slider({
              range: "min",
              value: 1,
              step: 1000,
              min: 0,
              max: 5000000,
              slide: function( event, ui ) {
                  $( "input#edit-field-range-test" ).val( ui.value );
              }
          });

      }
    };
}(jQuery));
```

Now problems:

1. When logged in as admin, slider kinda works, but looks strange:

[image]

There is no knob and overall it looks graphically broken. Also it only works if I set "CDN jQuery and jQuery UI" in jquery_update settings to some value.

2. When watching as anonymous user, I'm getting in firebugs console:

> TypeError: $(...).slider is not a function

What I'm doing wrong?

**Added:** Oh, I realized that this slider is supposed to be unusable without theming. However the problem with anonymous user is still current.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that:

```
function THEME_preprocess_html(&$variables) {
    drupal_add_library('system', 'ui.slider');
}
```

is needed for query_ui to be available for anonymous users on every page.